# SQL Self Join Dates

Tags: sql, date, join, self

Im attempted to perform a self intersect on a table and am abit stuck, I've read alot about grouping etc but cant seem to find and actual example to help me generate a good output.

My source table looks like this...

[image]

From there i would like to achieve this...

[image]

Any help would be gratefully received.
Thanks

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: Please post, what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Since the "Order" column is sequential & without gaps per EmplID, a self left-join should do.

```
SELECT
e1.EmplID,
e1."Date",
e2."Date" AS "Next Date"
FROM EmployeeDates AS e1
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDates AS e2 ON (e2.EmplID = e1.EmplID AND e2."Order" = e1."Order" + 1)
ORDER BY e1.EmplID, e1."Order"
```

And if your database supports the window function LEAD then you can do it without self-join. And even without the "Order" column.

```
SELECT
EmplID,
"Date",
LEAD("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY EmplID ORDER BY "Date") AS "Next Date"
FROM EmployeeDates 
ORDER BY EmplID, "Date"
```

Well, at least if the "Date" column is a DATE type and not a some string type like CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT.  Since an alphabetic sort wouldn't return the same order as the "Order" column.